# How to solve error about implementing inherited abstract class method?

Tags: java, inheritance, error-handling

code-

```
new ItemListener() {
  public void ItemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
      pics.setIcon(pic[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
  }
}
```

I am getting the error,

> The new type ItemListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract
>   class method ItemListener.ItemStateChanged(ItemEvent)

Comment: I doubt your error message is like that. It should be lowercase `i`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent)

Comment: post the actual error please

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is an anonymous implementation of [`java.awt.event.ItemListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html), it should implement the method [`itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html#itemStateChanged-java.awt.event.ItemEvent-) - note the lowercase `i` in the API specification as opposed to the upper case `I` in your implementation.

Comment: Also, he can use @Override to be able to find out the reason of the error easier